# How to recover Elasticsearch deleted indices if I have a copy of data folder?

Tags: elasticsearch

I deleted all `elasticsearch` indices by accident by kibana `DELETE` request, It was really a huge amount of data there.

immediately after that; I copied `elasticsearch/6.4.0/data` folder which I have right now and it includes indices folder there.

My question is: is there any way that may help me recovering data again or at least a part of it from that data folder?

Comment: change path.data in elasticsearch.yml to the backup folder. Then start elastic and perform a GET _cat/indices?v . You can see the deleted index? If yes, which is the id of the index?

Comment: That id should be inside ./your_backup_folder_path/nodes/0/